# ActivityNotFoundException invoking an inner-class activity

Tags: android

I have a non-Activity class (let's call it "NonActivity") that needs to post a message and get user feedback.   I have a message activity (MsgActivity) class to do this.    But only Activity classes can call *startActivityForResult()* so I made an inner helper class in NoActivity:

```
  // just to provide an Activity to launch MsgActivity
  class ActivityMsgClass extends Activity  {

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Intent iMA = new Intent(this, MsgActivity.class);
            iMA.putExtra("MsgText", mParams[0]);
       ...blah blah ...
            iMA.putExtra("ButtonCode", iBtns);
            startActivityForResult(iMA,3);          
        }     
  }
```

My Activity class is declared in the Manifest thusly:

```
<activity android:name="ActivityMsgClass"
          android:configChanges="orientation"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait"
          android:launchMode="singleInstance"></activity>
```

But when I try to invoke it . . .

```
                Intent i = new Intent(ctx, ActivityMsgClass.class);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                ctx.startActivity(i);
```

... I get an ActivityNotFound exception.  I've also tried it without the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, and I've also tried qualifying the name in the manifest, e.g.,

```
<activity android:name=".NoActivity.ActivityMsgClass"
```

. . . to no avail.   What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technical solution is to specify the fully qualified activity path in the manifest.

The actual solution is to avoid doing this. Let activity be a public class, and not an inner class, this is just not good practice.

Comment: If I do that what's the best way to pass the parameters back and forth between the NonActivity and Activity classes?  One reason I wanted to use an inner class is so it had local access to NonActivity's variables.

Comment: It depends on the case, but usually, inner class is not the solution when working with activities.

Comment: I agree -  it made me queasy to use an inner class, as well, but I was stymied by how to get the data back and forth.  Static "globals"?  What do you suggest?

Comment: Again, depends on your needs. If you want to use globals, do it by extending `Application`.

Comment: I bit the bullet and made a separate Activity and used globals for parameter passing (yuck).

Answer (score 0):

In your manifeast file change like below and try...

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityMsgClass"
          android:configChanges="orientation"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait"
          android:launchMode="singleInstance"></activity>
<activity android:name=".MsgActivity"
              android:configChanges="orientation"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:launchMode="singleInstance"></activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

your activity name declaration should start with a period. declare it this way.

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityMsgClass"
      android:configChanges="orientation"
      android:screenOrientation="portrait"
      android:launchMode="singleInstance"></activity>
```

also make sure that the activity `MsgActivity` is also declared in the manifest.

Comment: No amount of qualifying it makes any difference.  I've tried .ActivityMsgClass, NoActivity.ActivityMsgClass, .NoActivity.ActivityMsgClass, and com.demo.test.NoActivity.ActivityMsgClass .    I'm guessing this either has something to do with it being an inner class, or trying to launch it from a non-Activity class.

Comment: have you also tried using the $ notation for the activity name oin the manifest?
but i dont get why you need this approach? Inner activities should be avoided as much as possible.
if you just want to access variables then protected static variables would be a better approach!